# How does priority work with multiple checkers in Flycheck mode?

Tags: flycheck

I have multiple syntax checkers installed for Flycheck (specifically `javascript-eslint` and `javascript-standard`).

The way I have them set up is not compatible (one demands semicolons, one prohibits them etc.) and my question is *how* does flycheck pick which one to use?

Currently their "predicate"s are both found and they are both enabled.

The only way I have found to make sure standard is used, is to disable eslint in my .emacs and close and reopen emacs.

Additionally, once I have done that, disabling standard and enabling eslint doesn't appear to do anything (even very obvious errors are not flagged).

Could I have some help on how to quickly switch between the two modes (or at least switch after visiting a buffer) and how to tell which checker is currently active?

Answer (score 1):

Flycheck picks the first existing syntax checker from `flycheck-checkers`. In other words, the order in `flycheck-checkers` defines the priority of syntax checkers.

If you want to ensure that `standard` is being used for your project set `flycheck-checker` to `javascript-standard` via [Directory Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html).  You can use `C-c ! s` to interactively switch between syntax checkers.

The verification buffer at `C-c ! v` tells you which checkers aren't disabled.  It won't tell you exactly which checkers are actually, but we [intend to fix that](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/1090).  We are also working on a refactoring that will make it easier to select just those syntax checkers you want via directory variables.